# Некорректно работает код с regex, cmatch

Tags: c++

Пишу программу, в которой пользователь вводит строку, и если есть совпадение с регулярным выражением, то это совпадение выводится. Но я уже несколько раз меняла регулярное выражение те, в которых не может быть ошибки, но код не работает все равно. Ошибка где-то в if или for.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main() {
std::cout<< "Enter your text: ";
std::string text;
std::cout << "\n";
std::getline(std::cin, text);
/////////////////////
std::cmatch result;
std::regex probel ("([abcd])");
if (std::regex_match(text.c_str(), probel))
   for(int i=0; i < result.size(); i++) 
   std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Пробовала и result писать в if, ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте попробуем быть логичными.

Вот представим себе, что я ничего не знаю о регулярных выражениях, а смотрю только на код.

я вижу, что переменная `result` типа `cmatch` объявлена, но до начала цикла даже инициализирована. Тогда по какой причине Вы ожидаете, что можете сделать цикл до `result.size()`?

Теперь попробуем сделать то, что Вы хотите.

Итак, `regex_match()` возвращает true, если в строке находится паттерн, заданный регулярным выражением.

Чтобы "пройти по всем вхождениям паттеран в строку" - как я понял, чаще используется  `regex_search()`

Вот пример использования:

```
    //string to be searched
    string mystr = "She sells_sea shells in the sea shore"; 


    // regex expression for pattern to be searched 
   
    regex regexp("s[a-z_]+"); 

    // flag type for determining the matching behavior (in this case on string objects)
    smatch m; 

    // regex_search that searches pattern regexp in the string mystr  
    regex_search(mystr, m, regexp); 

    cout<<"String that matches the pattern:"<<endl;
    for (auto x : m) 
        cout << x << " ";
```

Я этот пример скопировал вот из этой [статьи](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/regex-in-cpp/) - прошу прощения, что на английском, но адекватного русского перевода мне не попалось.

Мне кажется, теперь Вы сможете решить свою задачу.

И еще один небольшой совет. Пока Вы учитесь, и не пишете программ промышленного уровня - Вы можете пользоваться `using namespace std;`, и Ваш код станет занчительно короче и обозримее - благодаря отсутствию префикса `std::` буквально в каждой строке.

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: А задача то получилась?